# Check edittext change after setting text from API response

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need a small help in checking the text in an edittext, so in start of activity i get data from API and set in edittext and i want to check if user made and changes to that edittext, I tried using `addTextChangedListener` function but this made my Boolean variable true when i set data to editttext from API response.

So is there any other way to check if user did any changes to edittext. and also i have a form in my activity with many edittext, I can compare API response with edittext but it will be very lengthy. If there is no other option ill have to go with that. 
Thanks.

I tried finding this question on stackoverflow but didnt find the solution.

Comment: save the API response in a string and compare with EditText data to check whether any changes has been made, It would be better if you post your code

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan, Yes thats my last option to compare edittext text with API response as i mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a boolean variable in your Activity: `Boolean fromApi = false;`. 
Then before you set the text to the EditText: `fromApi = true;`  
In your textwatcher add at the beginning:

```
if (fromApi) {
    fromApi = false;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Working as per my requirement. I didn't wanted to compare my edit-text text with API response text.